# join same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my select query, I want to fetch the parent staff name from the same table.

```
 SELECT 
     master.staffId,
     master.name,
     DATE_FORMAT(master.joinDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS joinDate,
     master.commission,
     master.salary,place AS placeName,
     staffType,parent.name AS parentName 
  FROM 
     staff AS master
     LEFT JOIN place 
        ON place.placeId = master.placeId
     LEFT JOIN stafftype 
        ON stafftype.staffTypeId = master.staffTypeId
     left outer join staff AS parent 
        ON parent.staffId = master.staffId
                        ORDER BY name
```

Comment: how will that last join help you? It would not, logically, make any difference to the query result.

Comment: than which is best way to fetch record.. is that possible with inner query?...

Comment: Could you show how your staff table looks like? because now you join staff 1 on staff 1. i guess you have a column like master_id or something ?

Comment: staffId int,
staffTypeId int,
placeId int,
parentStaffId int,
name varchar,
joinDate date,
commission double,
salary double

Comment: this is my table structure and in parentStaffname i want to fetch name from this table 5th field where i am inserting staff name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at your comment i think you need this

```
 SELECT master.staffId,master.name,DATE_FORMAT(master.joinDate,'%d-%m-%Y') AS joinDate,master.commission,
                          master.salary,place AS placeName,staffType,parent.name AS parentName 
  FROM staff AS master
  LEFT JOIN place ON place.placeId = master.placeId
  LEFT JOIN stafftype ON stafftype.staffTypeId = master.staffTypeId
  left outer join staff AS parent ON parent.staffId = master.parentStaffId
  ORDER BY name
```

Comment: you joined the same user to itself id to id you needed to join id to parentStaffId

e.g. parent.staffId = master.parentStaffId